# Remove Inverted comma from like function in codeigniter 2

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, codeigniter

I am using `PostgreSQL` Database. create a search query in using codeigniter like function.

> $this->db->($colName."::text", $value)->get("datatables_demo");

```
SELECT * FROM "datatables_demo" WHERE  "first_name::text" like '%co%'
```

But in `PostgreSQL` shows error, I want output like that

```
 SELECT * FROM "datatables_demo" WHERE  first_name::text like '%co%'
```

Is there any option in codeigniter to remove inverted comma from like function
ihave tried to send false in 3<sup>rd</sup> argument false

```
$this->db->($colName."::text", $value, false)
```

Give any option to resolve this issue using like function

> Query:SELECT * FROM "datatables_demo" WHERE  "salary::text"  LIKE
>   '%320%' ESCAPE '!'

```
When i run this query in postgresql 
ERROR:  column "salary::text" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "datatables_demo" WHERE  "salary::text"  LIKE ...
                                               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "salary::text" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 40
```

But when i remove inverted comma from column it return result succuessfully

> SELECT * FROM "datatables_demo" WHERE  salary::text  LIKE '%320%'
>   ESCAPE '!'

Comment: you may see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835172/code-igniter-remove-single-quotes-from-where-in

Comment: try something like this `$query = $this->db->get('datatables_demo');
$this->db->like('first_name', $value);`

Comment: There is not specified any integer values in like function not in where. I know that where function allow to remove quotes. you have any answer to remove from like function

Comment: @jameshwartlopez its same work in liner or  $this->db->like('first_name', $value); $query = $this->db->get('datatables_demo'); I already tried it

Comment: can you please update your post with the error?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez I have updated my post

Comment: By saying `like function` are you thinking about codeigniter funciton or postgresql like function query?

Comment: @jameshwartlopez I am ask about codeigniter function which is automatically add inverted comma in column name. So that postgreSql has give error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you thinking of sql like function
try this.

```
$sql = ('SELECT * FROM datatables_demo WHERE salary::text LIKE ?');
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($value . '%'));
```

Comment: I have more than 10 columns to add like and column name will be dynamic in this case and columns can be vary with order by and limit so that i am avoiding to use static query .

Answer (score 0):

I think in codeigniter2 PostgreSql driver has like operator previous versions codes.
If you want to in use codeigniter like function to build query you have to make some change in codeigniter system database library
I am give you changes in this path

> system\database\drivers\postgre\postgre_driver.php

In line no 36

```
var $_escape_char = '"';
```

Replace with

```
var $_escape_char = '';
```

Your query output same as you expected o/p
BEST OF LUCK

Comment: no I have not say its bug, I said you are using higher version of PostgreSql   so that this changes you have to made